# SQL server GROUP BY, SUM and retrieve a column value

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I want to run a sql query against a SQL Server table named "report"

The table:

```
id     timestamp           num     subid   country        name        pay

1   1/30/2018  1:32         1       11        us          John        1.00
2   1/30/2018  1:40         1       11        us          John        1.00
3   1/30/2018  1:31         1       12        us          Smith       1.00
4   1/30/2018  1:31         1       12        us          Jan         1.00
5   1/30/2018  1:45         1       12        us          Jan         1.00
```

The desired result:

```
2   1/30/2018  1:40         1       11        us          John        2.00
3   1/30/2018  1:31         1       12        us          Smith       1.00
5   1/30/2018  1:45         1       12        us          Jan         2.00
```

What I want - I want to group by the following 4 columns:

```
num     subid   country   name
```

Then I want to sum all of the "pay" values for the grouped rows, select the most recent timestamp and the "id," which corresponds to the most recent timestamp.

I am struggling with finding the "id"

My query:

```
SELECT num, subid, country, name, 
SUM(pay) as pay_sum, MAX(timestamp) as timestamp_max, 
FROM report 
GROUP BY main_id, subid, country, name;
```

It gives me everything I need apart from the ID.

The question - how do I get the id of the grouped rows, where the id is the one matching the most recent timestamp?

Comment: This could be wrong, but it looks like you aren't getting the ID because you aren't selecting it.

Comment: Yes, I am not selecting it - when I do, I get an error since it is not in the "GROUP BY." This is the part I need help with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       id
       ,timestamp
       ,num
       ,subid
       ,country
       ,name
       ,SUM(pay) OVER (PARTITION BY num, subid, country, name) as pay
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY num, subid, country, name ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as RowNum
    FROM
       report
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    RowNum = 1
```

This is where windowed functions come in handy.  Using SUM() OVER instead of a group by and then using ROW_NUMBER() OVER you can then pick the row you want and get the aggregated sum.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6b0c6/5

Comment: Tested with a 100k table and it worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. For this one, I made your query a subquery then did a self join to get the id. I am assuming `main_id` = `num` in your code.

```
select
    table1.id,
    sub.*
from (
    SELECT 
        num, 
        subid, 
        country, 
        name, 
        SUM(pay) as pay_sum, 
        MAX(timestamp) as timestamp_max
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY num, subid, country, name
) as sub
join table1
    on table1.subid = sub.subid
    and table1.timestamp = sub.timestamp_max
    and table1.name = sub.name
    and table1.country = sub.country

 ;
```

sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76be8/7

Comment: Thank you. This does it almost 100%, the only issue I found is when I have records with the same 4 columns I tried to group by and the same timestamp. Then I end up with more records than I should. Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a1dec/1

Comment: Yup, this only works if uniqueness can be determined by the four columns. In your case, @Matt's answer will work better.